# Can we use StackExchange.Redis without using LUA scripting to connect redis server version 4.0.8?

Tags: c#, lua, stackexchange.redis

I need to connect `Redis` hosted in Pivotal cloud using `Stackexchange.Redis.Strongname` and `Microsoft.Web.Redissessionstate` provider dlls from my `C#` code.
Earlier we have used **LUA** scripting for adding keys and other operations . But due to some limitations and restrictions we have to connect the Redis without using LUA.

I was able to add session KEY to redis without using LUA from ***Stackexchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer***  .

But when the initial Web page of my application is loading, it throws an error `ERR Unknown Command EVALASHA` from `StackExchange.Redis`.

I have verified the entire application code and I couldn't see any places where we used the LUA scripting directly(both for set and Get methods)

I just want to know is there any situations  where the Redis dll internally converting our `GET/SET` calls to LUA scripts for connecting to Redis.

Can we use redis without LUA scripting for Redis version 4.0 and above ?

Comment: You can certainly use the clients exposed beside Lua, mostly the benefit of the Lua is for harnessing the Redis on the server side, which otherwise needs programming language like C and Go

Comment: Also a poorly formatted question with very less details, please check

https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve